# Wired ethernet connection broken after Windows 10 Updates *only over network switch*

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ethernet

I have a relatively recent PC, that came with Windows 10. Things worked OK. It is far from the router, and there are other devices near it, like a networked-printer, ... so the cable from the router goes into a 5-port switch, to which my PC is connected. As MS started incessantly sending updates about two months ago, my network connection stopped working. The effect is as if someone would un-plug and re-plug the cable every second or so. My PC is set to use DHCP; nothing manually defined, like DNS ... I have tried the following to debug the problem:

- Look at the switch lights: the light for the PC is "blinking" every second or so.
- Look at the state of the network connection in Network and Sharing: It goes on, off, on, off, ... every second or so.
- Change cable between PC and switch: No effect.
- Change port used by PC on switch: No effect.
- Change port used by cable to router on switch: No effect.
- Check network driver updates: It is already up to date.
- Check other devices on the switch can access the Internet: they can.
- Searched on the internet and tried several proposed solutions (like resetting DNS and ip4, ...): So far, no effect.
- Looked at other similar questions here: They all have a different problem.
- Plugged router cable directly into PC: **It works** (but then all my other nearby devices loose network connectivity)

Clearly, neither the switch, nor the cable, nor my network card, nor my PC as a whole is broken. No hardware or router change was performed before the problem started. One day I was on the PC and everything was fine, and then MS said it was installing updates, and then the next day it stopped working.

I have tried de-installing updates, but the problem did not go away. OTOH, since many updates are "locked", that is cannot be de-installed, it might well be one of those that broken my connection.

If all else fails, I will order a new switch, be the switch hardware is clearly working, so I have no real hope of solving the problem like that. Also, even if I could pull another cable from the router to my PC, I do not have a free port on my router to plug it in.

Is this a know problem with an existing solution (I could not formulate a search that found this problem specifically)?

What could I still try, beyond buying a new switch?

Has the TCP/IP been updated recently such that a new switch could have some new "feature" that Windows 10 expects, but the old switch doesn't have?

Comment: "Has the TCP/IP been updated recently such that a new switch could have some new "feature" that Windows 10 expects, but the old switch doesn't have?" TCP/IP hasn't changed in 30 years

Comment: @Ramhound That is what I was assuming. IP6 is relatively new, but within the LAN it should be IP4 anyway, so I don't think it's that either.